# Setting textbox properties on continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on an Access 2010 form which where the user can select a record in the form header via a combobox and then build up elements related to the selected record in the detail section of the form.  The default view of the form is set to continuous forms.

One of the controls in the detail section of the form is a combobox control.  What I want to do is set the enabled property of a textbox on the same row of the form to false based upon a selection from the combobox.  The code I am running is:

```
If Me.cboElementType = "Contract Shrink" Then
  Me.txtElementID = ""
  Me.txtElementID.Enabled = False
EndIf
```

This works, but it sets all instances of the textbox (txtElementID) to enabled = false.  What I want to have happen is for the txtElementID to have a different enabled setting for each row in the detail section based upon the selection of the combobox cboElementType.  So, if cboElementType = "Contract Shrink" on row 1 of the scrolling detail section, the txtElementID.Enabled would be set to false for that row.  If cboElementType = "Cost Group" on row 2 of the scrolling detail section, then I'd like txtElementID.Enabled to be False on row 1 of the detail section and txtElementID.Enabled to be True on row 2.

Can anyone confirm or deny that this can be done and, if it can be done, how you would suggest it be accomplished?  No matter which way this goes, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it through VBA like you did, you need to use Conditional formatting, there you have an option to set the `Enabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

try in  Form_Current()  event like

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Me.cboElementType = "Contract Shrink" Then
  Me.txtElementID = ""
  Me.txtElementID.Enabled = False
EndIf
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for days for how to access an individual record on continuous form and I am willing to say it is not possible, but I have a trick that I will share here.  I have an investments database, user gets in and writes a proposal and then there is a meeting where either the project is approved (given money) or it is cancelled.  However, there are many more states a project can be in, Proposal, Execution, etc. but only Approved/Cancelled can happen at this stage.  I created a MockBool field in the Project table.  I put that on the continuous form and when the form is closed I run this:

```
rs_frm=me.recordset
rs_frm.movefirst
while not(rs_frm.eof)
  if rs_frm("MockBool") then
    rs_frm.edit
    rs_frm("ProcessStatus")="Cancelled"
    rs_frm("MockBool")=false
    rs_frm.update
  end if
  rs_frm.movenext
wend
```

I had days of searching and had an epiphany so I thought I would share.

Comment: Don't see how this answers question.